# How to iterate over every page returned by a JPA Criteria?

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I need to build a background process that will periodically process all the elements of a database table.
Since I can not load all the elements in memory, I need to divide the database in subportions. Unfortunately, I can not use JPQL Stream return type, since the query uses a complex filter based logic which is not achievable by writing a JPQL query.

Thus, I have built the following criteria query, to return only a page of Products. After I have processed a page, how can I iterate over next one until I have processed them all?

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils;

@Repository
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductRepositoryImpl implements CustomProductRepository {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Page<Product> getProducts(Pageable pageable, /* fields used to filter the results */) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Product> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Product.class);
        Root<Product> root = criteriaQuery.from(Product.class);
        
        List<Predicate> predicates = getPredicates(/* fields used to filter the results */);

        criteriaQuery.where(combinePredicatesWithAndStatement(criteriaBuilder, predicates))
            .orderBy(QueryUtils.toOrders(pageable.getSort(), root, criteriaBuilder));

        List<Product> result = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
            .setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset())
            .setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize())
            .getResultList();

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilderCount = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilderCount.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<Product> rootCount = countQuery.from(Product.class);

        List<Predicate> predicatesCount = getPredicates(/* fields used to filter the results */);

        countQuery.select(criteriaBuilderCount.count(rootCount))
            .where(combinePredicatesWithAndStatement(criteriaBuilderCount, predicatesCount));

        Long totalElements = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();

        return new PageImpl<>(result, pageable, totalElements);
    }

    private List<Product> getPredicates(/* fields used to filter the results */) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
        // assemble predicates based on some complex conditions not replicable with JPQL
        return predicates;
    }

    private Predicate combinePredicatesWithAndStatement(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, List<Predicate> predicates) {
        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(Predicate[]::new));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over all the pages you can create a PageStreamer class as follows:

```java
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Slice;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class PageStreamer<T> {

    private final Pageable pageable;
    private final Function<Pageable, Page<T>> getPage;

    public PageStreamer(Pageable pageable, Function<Pageable, Page<T>> getPage) {
        this.pageable = pageable;
        this.getPage = getPage;
    }

    public Stream<Page<T>> stream() {
        val currentPageableReference = new AtomicReference<>(pageable);

        return Stream.generate(currentPageableReference::get)
            .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(getPage)
            .takeWhile(Slice::hasContent)
            .map(page -> setNextPageable(page, currentPageableReference));
    }

    private Page<T> setNextPageable(Page<T> page, AtomicReference<Pageable> currentPageableReference) {
        currentPageableReference.set(page.hasNext() ? page.nextPageable() : null);
        return page;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```java
PageStreamer<Product> pageStreamer = new PageStreamer<>(
    // starts retrieving the products from the first page,
    // using a 50 elements window size
    PageRequest.of(0, 50),
    pageable -> productRepository.getProducts(pageable, /* fields used to filter the results */)
);

pageStreamer.stream().forEach(product -> {
    // perform some processing
});
```